# Insert woocommerce products programmatically with featured image and gallery

Tags: posts, woocommerce-offtopic, attachments, media-library, array

I'm inserting WooCommerce products programmatically to the database, but I'm having trouble inserting and linking first image as featured image and multiple images for gallery assigned respectively to each product from multiple URLs, Would you have any idea how to do it?

```
<?php
    if(!empty($girls))
    {
        $ops = array_map('str_getcsv', file(get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/'. $girls));
        
        $myres = array_map('array_filter', $ops);
        $ops2 = array_filter($myres);
        
        $items = array();
        foreach($ops2 as $username) {
        $items[] = $username;
        }

        foreach ($items as $it) {
            

            $title = array_key_exists(2, $it) ? $it[2] : null;
            $description = array_key_exists(3, $it) ? $it[3] : null;
            // Multiple images in each key
            $img = array_key_exists(4, $it) ? $it[4] : null;
            $secimg = explode(';', $img);
            $category = array_key_exists(5, $it) ? $it[5] : null;
            $price = array_key_exists(8, $it) ? $it[8] : null;
            $stock = array_key_exists(6, $it) ? $it[6] : null;
            
                    foreach ($secimg as $rurl) {
                    // <img height="200px" src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/'.$newtxt[0].'"/>
                    
                        $postarr = array(
                            'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags($title),
                            'post_name' => $title,
                            'post_content' => $description,
                            'post_type' => 'product',
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                        );
                        $insert_id = wp_insert_post($postarr, true);

                        
                        foreach ($secimg as $rurl) {
                            if($rurl){
                                
                                // <img height="200px" src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/'.$newtxt[0].'"/>
                                    $image_url = "https://static.wixstatic.com/media/";
                                    $image_url .= $rurl;//This is the sanitized image url.


                            $urlimg = download_url( $image_url);
    
                            update_post_meta($insert_id, '_product_image_gallery', implode(',', array_keys($urlimg)));
                            
                            //update_post_meta($post_id,  array_push($post_id, '_product_image_gallery', $value ));
                        }

                    }


                    //set Product Category
                    wp_set_object_terms($insert_id, $category, 'product_cat');

                    //set product type
                    wp_set_object_terms($insert_id, 'simple', 'product_type');

                    update_post_meta( $insert_id, '_price', $price );
                    update_post_meta($insert_id, '_sku', $stock);
                    update_post_meta($insert_id, 'total_sales', '0');
                    
                }// End first foreach
            
            
        }

    }?>
```

Comment: Why not use the Woocommerce built in rest api? it gives you a endpoint that you can pass a payload with everything you need, see [create a product](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product), you can add the categories, meta data, image, gallery, price etc... for that product

Comment: I already tried. But my CSV file crashes this tool certainly because there is a problem with the multiple images of the file so I have to create a script to insert my 1200 products programmatically.

Comment: that's a very longwinded way to create an attachment and attach it, is there a reason you didn't use the sideloading helper functions? `media_sideload_image` would download the image, move it to the right place, create the attachment, and attach it to your post all in one function call

Comment: `$thumbnail = media_sideload_image( $image_url, $insert_id ... etc)`. Also are you sure that `$image_url = $secimg;` is correct? `$secimg` is created from a call to `explode`, and `explode` returns an array/list, not a string.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the function you suggested but I got the following error:

"
Uncaught TypeError: array_keys(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, WP_Error given in"